# About Data List in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

what is the difference between Data list and Grid view

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` has much more bells and whistles than `DataList`. The very basic difference is that you should write your own templates to use a `DataList`. `GridView` automatically provides you with a tabular data template and much more functionality out of the box. The rule of thumb is, use `GridView` when it's what you need. Use `DataList`, `Repeater` and other more customizable controls when you're willing to customize them more radically.

Answer (score 0):

A datalist is more for display data in different layouts like a corporate phonebook with images that you want to make the columns horizontal instead of vertical like a table format.  The downside to a datalist is you can't edit the data easily meaning it can be done but you have to write your own procedures to do it.  With a gridview it's all built in for editing.

Here's a good explanation of each of the data bound controls in .net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214(vs.80).aspx